# Sql 'like' condition inside 'exists'

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

I have 2 Mysql tables

1. **products** with varchar columns **equ** and **lik**
2. **preferences** with varchar columns **equ** and **lik**

I want to select everything from products with condition that there is at least one row in preferences that preferences.equ **equals to** products.equ **and** products.lik **is like** %preferences.lik%. I.e products.lik includes preferences.lik as substring. How to build this query?

Comment: Do you have any need to see data from preferences?

Comment: @TheImpaler MySql

Comment: @xQbert I haven't any need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build it pretty much as you described it:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (select 1
              from preferences pr
              where pr.equ = p.equ and
                    p.lik like concat('%', pr.lik, '%')
             );
```